# using XMPPFrameWork in IOS

Tags: ios, xmppframework

i am working on a chat app in ios and using XMPPFrameWork.

i used code from this link :

[click here.](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-integration/)

but in this code xmpp library not attached. i download library from

[from here](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)

and include this in my project. but now my project failed to compile. and giving errortrace :

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/quytech/Documents/nitin_work/Twinqli IOS/Building-a-Jabber-client-for-iOS-master 3/xmpp/Vendor/libidn"'
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SSLClose", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket closeWithError:] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLCreateContext", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLGetBufferedReadSize", referenced from:
      ___33-[GCDAsyncSocket flushSSLBuffers]_block_invoke in GCDAsyncSocket.o
      -[GCDAsyncSocket doReadData] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLHandshake", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_continueSSLHandshake] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLRead", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket flushSSLBuffers] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
      -[GCDAsyncSocket doReadData] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetCertificate", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetConnection", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetEnabledCiphers", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetIOFuncs", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetPeerDomainName", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetProtocolVersionMax", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetProtocolVersionMin", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLWrite", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket doWriteData] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

can anyone help me for compiling this project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure **libidn** directory is exist in path. If it is still not found then change path of **libidn** and try to build it

Comment: yes libidn directory exist in path . i have checked it.

Comment: make sure that you have added all the required libraries

Comment: i have Solved problem by just adding security framework.

Comment: @DeepakKumar yes it is solved by adding security framework

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue first check whether libdin.a & all other useful libraries are added in your project or not. If you dont have it you can download it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/xremoteplatform/source/browse/trunk/practice/lib/libidn.a?r=5), clean your project & run it.
If still the problem persists, follow these steps to add security.framework:
Project -> Build Phases -> Link library with binaries -> click + button at bottom left -> search for security.framework -> add it , after that clean your project & build it. It will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use **cocoapods** (http://cocoapods.org/?q=XMPPFramework). Automatically configures all the project for you and you forget to do manually.